# "Is there any repository or documentation with instructions to run docker created by django oscar?"

Tags: django, docker, django-oscar

I am working with Django oscar docker and in the meantime found that Django oscar sandbox not installing as expected. So I want to get rid of all hassles and want to run it in docker. When I went through Django oscar GitHub repository and their docker hub profile I found no instructions and guideline to run it. I have also created an issue to their GitHub profile and they suggested me to ask questions on StackOverflow or google group. For a faster response, I am asking help from this community. Hope you guys will come up. This is my github issue link

https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/issues/3051

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have pulled the image locally using docker pull, run `docker run -d -p 8080:8080 oscarcommerce/django-oscar-sandbox` and access the sandbox on http://localhost:8080/.

Comment: Thanks for answering, will upvote and accept it after checking, thank you.